# PrestaShop admin login

Tags: authentication, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm new in Prestashop and I've created my account.
When I login in the Admin page it doesn't take me to another one. It stays in the same page of logging in without my email and password like a refresh but when I type a false password I get this message:

`There is one error.
The employee does not exist, or the password provided is incorrect`

Comment: Have you deleted cookies?

Comment: No I didn't should I do ? Cz I just started

Comment: Try it and let me know. It happens sometimes if you've been messing up between frontoffice/backoffice.

Comment: Nothing Happened !

Comment: This situation is different than the previous one. Recover password.

Comment: There is one error.
An error occurred while attempting to reset your password..     I got this msg  please can you give me your email to send you a video recorded about my situation , I just started learning PrestaShop and Im lost

Comment: Please open a thread at PrestaShop forum

Comment: I already posted this question at PrestaShop forum but no answers

Comment: Could you paste the link?

Comment: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/663325-login-error/?page=0#comment-2680769

Comment: I answered there but no answer from you